# How to deny Assert with CAS?

Tags: .net, cas, permissions

In this code, I'd like the ReadFileSystem method to be forbidden to Assert a permission on the filesystem.

I expected this will throw at fileIo.Assert(), but it doesn't. Why?

```
using System.Security.Permissions;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var fileIo = new FileIOPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
    var secuPerm = new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Assertion);
    PermissionSet set = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
    set.AddPermission(fileIo);
    set.AddPermission(secuPerm);
    set.Deny();
    ReadFileSystem();
    Console.Read();
}

private static void ReadFileSystem()
{
    var fileIo = newFileIOPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
    fileIo.Assert();

    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("C:/");
    dir.GetDirectories();
}
```

***Update***

Great link here on CAS : http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2004/08/25/220458.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The subsequent Assert negates the effects of the Deny.

The ability to assert FileIOPermission mainly depends on whether your assembly is trusted. It is not affected by a previous Deny of FileIOPermission. It turns out that it is also not affected by the previous Deny of the Assertion SecurityPermission. **This is because SecurityPermissionFlag.Assertion is checked as a link time demand.** This is not clearly documented; I found it [here](http://www.grimes.demon.co.uk/workshops/secWSSix.htm#link_demands).

To force the CLR to not trust your assembly for FileIOPermission, you can use the following at the top of your file following the using statements. When you add this to your file, the assert will not take effect. This affects the entire assembly. There is no finer granularity.

```
[assembly:FileIOPermission(SecurityAction.RequestRefuse, Unrestricted=true)]
```

Comment: binarycoder is exactly right.  .NET rarely Asserts internally... It usually Demands.  Demand is what does the stack walk that would find the deny on the stack and fail.  For all file IO .NET does a Demand.  But as soon as it finds an Assert on the stack the stack walk is stopped short.

Comment: And as binarycoder suggested, the only way to keep Assert from doing its work is to deny the entire assembly the permissions you are trying to assert, effectively making your assembly run with partial trust.  Partial trust is good, but if you don't want to be able to call Assert, just don't call it?

Comment: @Andrew, I wanted to be sure that any call after my Assert can not access the hard drive. Because my use case was to call another assembly via reflection (not trusted), without having to configure the evidence when I load it. Finally, it's what I've done. But this behavior of CAS intrigued me.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may misunderstand the purpose of Asserting permissions.  When you Assert a permission set in CAS, you are effectively saying "I know what I'm doing... I don't care what the permissions are deeper in the stack."  That's almost *never* what you want.  You generally want to Demand a permission set.  That causes a stack walk, which would find the Deny on the stack and then cause a security exception.

However, since .NET has virtually all the necessary Demands built-in, there's rarely a need to actually Demand anything unless you're doing Asserts (again, that's rare) or you've written your own custom Permission class.

Comment: Yes I know that, but I thought that when we do Assert, there was a stack walk for the SecurityPermission. (The MSDN says clearly that you can assert if your assembly has the permission on the asserted permission AND that you have SecurityPermission granted on your assembly).

Comment: Neither of those things that MSDN says occurs requires a stack walk.

Comment: Sure, it was my mistake. But your assembly should be allowed with the SecurityPermission and the Assertion flag. (In the config of .NET or within your assembly code like binary coder said)